# Как взять цвет с одного div и как применить его фоном для другого при click?

Tags: javascript

Например взять красный цвет или зеленый с квадрата и закрасить круг этим цветом?

```css
.red{
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.green{

   width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.circle{
  
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red" ></div>
<br>
<div class="green"></div>

<br>

<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Читаем про `getComputedStyle`. Но к сожалению или к счастью., кому как, не будет работать в некоторых браузерах, например в мозе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".red, .green").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    document.querySelector(".circle").style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(this).backgroundColor;
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}

.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<br>
<div class="green"></div>
<br>
<div class="circle"></div>
```